# how to do redhat7.5 hardware compatibility test?

Tags: compatibility

I have installed Redhat7.5 in X3650 M3 which is an IBM server and not in the Redhat7.5 hardware support list.

During the installation no error or warning is reported . But I still want to do some hardware compatibility test, can you give me some advices about the hardware compatibility test?